# How to connect through socket to Virtual Machine

Tags: sockets, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have a java client on Windows and c++ server running on Linux (VM). I'm trying to connect client to the server. But I don't know what IP address I should use. 
My Virtual Machine configuration is default, I have NAT network on it. 
Here is what I get from ifconfig

```
enp0s3    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:97:86:ce 
      inet addr:10.0.2.15  Bcast:10.0.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::8651:2c9d:6683:e4fc/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:855910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:267095 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:940974525 (940.9 MB)  TX bytes:24398399 (24.3 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:9710 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9710 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1
      RX bytes:875898 (875.8 KB)  TX bytes:875898 (875.8 KB)
```

And here is what i get from ipconfig:

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Połączenie lokalne* 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ddca:c63d:1b9e:6255%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254

Ethernet adapter Połączenie sieciowe Bluetooth:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Połączenie lokalne* 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:9d38:90d7:10c9:14d5:da7f:e55c
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::10c9:14d5:da7f:e55c%13
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

I tried to connect using:

```
socket = new Socket("10.0.2.15", 1236);
```

When Im using client on VM with localhost everything is fine.

So I assume there is a problem with connection between Windows and VM.

Answer (score 5):

you should read https://blogs.oracle.com/scoter/networking-in-virtualbox-v2

Basically, you have to configure the port forwarding. Follow the instructions provided in the link, by the end of the page.

The configuration you shoud use is:

```
Name: Rule 1 (or any actually)
Protocol: TCP
Host IP: 127.0.0.1
Host Port: 1236
Guest IP: (leave blank)
Guest Port: 1236
```

The guest port could be any, but must be the same you are using on your server application. Leave the Guest IP blank.

Now, in order to you connect from the host to the guest, you should use in the client application:

```
socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1236);
```

If you want to connect from the guest VM to the host machine, using this configuration, you should use in the client application instead:

```
socket = new Socket("10.0.2.2", 1236);
```

Alternatively, you could also use the NIC in bridge mode, also explained in the article. But you should configure the router properly.

Btw, don't forget to disable your firewall, or configure it, otherwise it can block the incoming connections.
You can disable ufw using the command:

```
sudo ufw disable
```